# Can Jenkins Pipeline checkout a commit that has not been merged?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit

I am attempting to test a Jenkinsfile, with docker images, and various tests using a Jenkins Pipeline. I am able to checkout the latest code from Gerrit using a branch name or a merged commit hash. But, want to know if it is possible to test using an un-merged commit hash. I am trying to test this using a commit before it is merged for the following reasons:

1. In case the commit breaks existing code.
2. In case my docker images and other files are not actually set up properly. If I were to find an error in the Jenkinsfile or other configuration files, I would have to keep pushing code until I get it right.

Is this possible? How do you all test your files and pipeline before merging?

The following is my Jenkinsfile syntax:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout git repository') {
            agent any
            steps {
                checkout([
                    $class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: '<un-merged commit hash>']],
                    extensions: [[$class: 'WipeWorkspace']],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[
                        credentialsId: '<credentials hash>',
                        url: '<git repository url>'
                    ]]
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We use Gerrit Code Review (https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) - it uses intermediary refs/for branches, where changes stay until they have been reviewed by another developer, and verified by Jenkins. Only then can changes be merged into the actual refs/heads branch. Works quite well, but is not a small thing to introduce.

Comment: So, we actually use Gerrit here too (just edited my post to reflect that), that is why I was thinking it would be easy to checkout a specific commit, since Jenkins and Gerrit usually work well together.

Any notes on how you might use the intermediary refs/for branches to checkout? It does not seem to work for me given my syntax in the original post.

Comment: Why not build the pull requests?

Comment: I was able to successfully get this working with everyone's help. I chose to use the Gerrit Trigger plugin since I already had this installed on my Jenkins instance.
I trigger a build on a +2 Code Review using the Gerrit Trigger plugin. I really like this plugin because of all the options that can be used to trigger a build.


For the pipeline configuration in the _Branches to Build_ field I specify: `$GERRIT_REFSPEC`.

And I set up the _Script Path_ to point to my Jenkinsfile in my Gerrit directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the Jenkins file with your code and use the [Gerrit Trigger plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger). This make it all very easy without you having to specify any complicated git url.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a look at [Gerrit Code Review Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Code+Review+Plugin) as well. It is easier to setup than Gerrit Trigger plugin.

I wrote a [blog post](https://gitenterprise.me/2019/03/12/jenkins-ci-and-gerrithub-io-integration-the-easy-way/) with the comparison between the two a while ago, I hope it can help.